# Дана строка. Определить, сколько слов заканчивается введенной пользователем буквой

Tags: c

Не выводит число, помогите, в чем ошибка? После проверок ничего не происходит, просто программа заканчивается(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char s[30];
int i,kolvo=0,n;
printf("Введите строку\n ");
gets(s);
printf("Вот она %s\n",s);
printf("Введите букву\n ");
scanf("%c",n);

for (i=0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{if ((s[i] == (' ') || (s[i] == ('.')))&&(s[i - 1]==(n))) kolvo++;}

printf("%d\n",kolvo);



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прокомпилировал, и несколько ошибок у вас нашёл. Вы в `scanf` аргумент с мусором стека заводите, а функция думает, что это адрес и прога падает. Нужно передавать адрес переменной с типом `char`. Дальше `gets` устаревшая функция, поменял на `fgets`. Пока пашет. Читайте инструкции к функциям внимательно. Цикл поиска пробелов нужно начинать со второй буквы, а то может опять всё упасть если первая буква будет пробелом.

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c11 strilett.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char s[30];
int i,kolvo=0/*,n*/;
char  let ;
printf(u8"Введите строку\n ");
fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);
printf(u8"Вот она %s\n",s);
printf(u8"Введите букву\n ");
scanf("%c",& let);

for (i=1; i < strlen(s); i++){
  if ((s[i] == (' ') || (s[i] == ('.')))&&
      (s[i - 1]==(let)))
    kolvo++;}

printf("%d\n",kolvo);

return 0;}
```

Comment: За `for (i=1; i < strlen(s); i++){` надо руки отрывать.

Comment: Я устал уже считать баги. До `strlen` дело не дошло. Это всего-лишь оптимизация. А вы что имели в виду? @Qwertiy

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Qwertiy, А что плохого здесь конкретно в `strlen()`? (Нет, я понимаю про стили и всё такое, но всё же для новичка...) Или вы правда думаете, что компилятор настольно глуп?

Comment: А что обозначают эти тайные `u8` в коде?

Comment: По привычке поставил тип кодировки строки. u8 = char(UTF8) , u=char16 U=char32 L=wchar16  Я проверял, и исходник у меня на UTF8. @0andriy

Comment: @0andriy, компилятор не будет выносить strlen. Из-за этого у алгоритма квадратичная асимптотика вместо линейной.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы проверяли? Можете показать командную строку запуска компилятора и результирующий ассемблерный код цикла?

Comment: @0andriy, VS2010 точно оставлял в цикле.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Передавайте привет известной компании!

Comment: @0andriy, кстати, не факт, что при любом теле цикла компилятор может быть уверен, что строка не меняется.

Comment: @0andriy, вот - небольшое изменение - и всё оно в цикле даже в gcc с `-O3`: https://godbolt.org/z/be2nmK